# How do I redirect a state child ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to do that when users enter the URL '/id/: numberTag' I enter a default state, as I have this code:

App.js

```
.run(function($rootScope, $state){
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
            if (to.redirectTo) {
                evt.preventDefault()
                $state.go(to.redirectTo, params)
            }
        });
  })
```

In my file Router.js:

```
   $stateProvider
            .state('detail', {
                url: '/:section/:numberTag',
                abstract: true,
                template: require('raw!./templates/detail.html'),
                controller: 'mainCtrl',
                redirectTo: 'detail.biography'
            })
                .state('detail.biography', {
                    url: '/biography',
                    template: require('raw!./templates/biograpy.html'),
                    controller: 'BiograpyCtrl',
                    data: {
                        'selectedTab': 0
                    },
                })
```

Upon entering the user url page is blank.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add this feature in the app.run:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(evt, to, params) {
      var path = location.pathname;

      ///id/RXRVFN/biography

        if( path.match(/\/id\/[^\/]+\/?$/) ){
            location.pathname = path+'biography'
        }

    })
```